# É melhor utilizar overloading ou adicionar um "if" com o parâmetro opcional?

Tags: c#, estilo-de-codificação, sobrecarga

Tenho um método na qual um atributo pode não ser utilizado

Nesse caso se o valor passado não for vazio ele adiciona o parâmetro ao meu e-mail

```
public async Task<bool> SendEmail(string to, string subject, string body,string unsubscribeHeaderUrl = "")
{ 
    using (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage())
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(unsubscribeHeaderUrl)) mail.Headers.Add("List-Unsubscribe",unsubscribeHeaderUrl);
    }
}
```

Porém posso fazer isso utilizando o [Overloading](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-method-overloading/) fazendo assim:

```
public async Task<bool> SendEmail(string to, string subject, string body,string unsubscribeHeaderUrl = "")
{ 
    using (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage())
    {
        mail.Headers.Add("List-Unsubscribe",unsubscribeHeaderUrl);
        //Restante do processo
    }
}

public async Task<bool> SendEmail(string to, string subject, string body)
{ 
    using (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage())
    {
        //Restante do processo
    }
}
```

Qual é a forma correta de se fazer? utilizar um `if` ou [*overloading*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-method-overloading/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende, como sempre. na maioria dos casos o que for mais simples. Para este caso me parece que o primeiro caso é melhor porque é mais simples, eu prefiro sempre o mais simples, inclusive porque ele é naturalmente DRY que é o princípio mais importante da programação.

Se pensar em termos de performance não deve mudar muito e o segundo pode ser pior dependendo de como fizer, apesar de ter um *branch* e isso tem um custo maior é pequeno e só em casos de precisar extrema performance é que vale o esforço, mas o tempo que isto gastará no método `MailMessage()` é tão maior que não faz diferença ter isso a mais.

O primeiro só custará mais caro se você repetir o mesmo código nos dois métodos, o que pode violar o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) e causar possível futuros problemas de manutenção. Uma solução para isto seria criar um método utilitário para chamá-lo e não repetir o código, mas aí a chamada custará mais caro que o *branch*  do `if`, a não ser que ele seja privado e possa ser otimizado, mas o uso de `using` impede a otimização *inline*, então será muito mais caro, não compensa.

Só tem um detalhe o primeiro exemplo faz algo diferente do segundo, então se isso não foi um acidente nada disso vale e aí o segundo deveria ser seguido pelo simples fato dele fazer o que deve ser feito nos dois casos. Se foi um acidente, é um dos motivos para evitar fazer dois códigos separados, parece que está fazendo a mesma coisa e não estão, por isso eu valorizo muito o DRY, a questão é saber se o código é canônico ou não para decidir o que deve ser, por isso recomendo fortemente a leitura da outra pergunta *linkada*.

Answer (score 0):

Sua dúvida diz respeito a padrões de projeto, ou seja a resposta vai depender deste requisito. Mas, Ambos os casos funcionam, mas utilizar o Overloading fica muito mais elegante, além de tornar de fácil compreensão.